# How can I generate a reference number in a certain pattern in php

Tags: php, random

I would like to generate a sequential number.

basically I have a form and on that form is a textbox for a 
reference number - I would like that number generated. Ideally I would 
like it to be in the format of '`MB.P1.A`, all sequential, 
nothing random.

I am not sure how to go about this. whether it needs to be a database 
thing or text file thing.

**MB** is constant but the number after **P** will change randomly as well as the last letter.

How can I do this in php?

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you to achieve what you want.

```
function returnRandomRefNumber(){
    return "MB.P".rand(0,9).chr(rand(65,90));
}
```